# how to Video capture of the computer on the network?

Tags: networking, video-capture, capture, screen-capture

We have a network in our office.
And i want to get video capture of another computer's screen
from my computer.
Do you know any software for this.
Thank you.

Comment: Unless you are trying to create such a program, your question is better suited on superuser.

Comment: :) i am not trying create such a program, i there is any program doing what i want in the world, please tell me...

Comment: I am afraid that this question will probably get closed.

Comment: :) May be i can't explain. Because i'm not english and my english is not good as yours

Answer (score 0):

see TeamViewer software.

you can use ffmpeg to to stream other desktop in your network.

Comment: But TeamViewer works via internet. Doesn't it. I want to capture via LAN.

Answer (score 0):

Streaming your desktop to another computer is almost as cpu-consuming as capturing it on the same computer. If you want to avoid cpu/gpu usage the best option is a CAPTURE CARD conected via cables. You can buy one for about 50$-40€ and conect the output of your PC to the input. They usually have audio input too and a capture software with some editing tools. PINNACLE is a good brand if you ask me.

Anyways, there is a software: TeamViewer, that might be what you're looking for.